# Descobrir qual Botão foi Clicado, e fazer um if

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite, sou novo na programação web estou com uma dificuldade, saber se alguém pode me ajuda?

Tenho 2 formulários um fica sobre o outro para usuário só mostra um formulário por vez, os 2 formulários tem nomes e componentes diferentes, um é a tela de login, e outro a tela para recuperar a senha, um tem um botão login e outro tem o botão redefinir, quero que quando clica em um desses botões me retorne uma string com nome do botão.

exemplo

```
var nomeBtn

if nomeBtn = 'login' then
 let form = document.getElementById('formLogin');
 let submit = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
elseif nomeBtn = 'redefinir' then
 let form = document.getElementById('formRedefinor');
 let submit = document.getElementById('btnRedefinir');
end if
```

Usei um pouco de `VBA` com `Javascript` mais tudo seria para `Javascript`, pq sei programar em VBApor isso usei o if VBA por não saber muito o if do Javascript

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Esse 'form...'  são inputs ?

Comment: quando associar um evento como o "click" por  exemplo a um função, é possível passar o elemento que fez o click como parâmetro, e saber qual foi. Sugiro primeiro portar seu código para javascript e criar algo básico como o um *handler* para o evento click, para ai então poder chegar nessa parte do código que está

Comment: são inputs dentro do formulário

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um eventListener no documento e dizer pra fazer o que você quer em uma função, exemplo:

`document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ console.log(e.target); });`

Isso vai retornar o elemento que foi clicado, mas se tu quiser que apareça o id você pode por algo tipo dentro da função ali encima:

`console.log(e.target.getAttribute('id'));`

Testa aí e me avisa se tiver funcionado

Comment: não conseguir, o primeiro botão login ele não carrega nada no console

Comment: Como ficou o código depois dessa função que eu falei?